# Cómo generar un ArrayList con li en html a través de la base de datos de Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, array, firebase

Estoy intentando hacer una lista trabajando con li en html, ya tengo funcionando la lista, pero necesito que esta se genere automáticamente a través de los datos obtenidos en Firebase...

Esta es la referencia en Firebase

```
firebase.database().ref().child("Usuarios").orderByChild("Número");
```

Esta es la forma en que genero la lista

```
var options = [
        set0 = ['Opción 1','Opción 2'],
        set1 = ['Primera Opción','Segunda opción','Tercera opción']
    ];

function makeUL(array) {

    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

        var item = document.createElement('li');


        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));


        list.appendChild(item);
    }


    return list;
}

document.getElementById('foo').appendChild(makeUL(options[0]));
```

De qué forma podría unir firebase con esta lista que estoy generando, en vez de poner manualmente los datos en el var options, hacerlo a través de los datos que quiero obtener en Firebase.

Espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias!